# How to get a json ResponseBody that prints a referenced entity's selected field?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to be able to do the following 2 things:

1. Return with a json representation of the object Organizer.
2. Return with a json representation of the object Party, but only prints the Organizer's id.
3. Return with a json representation of the object Party, but only prints the Organizer's firstName.

If I annotate the class Party's Organizer field with the @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonIdentityReference annotations as shown below, it satisfies conditions 1 & 2 above.

However, how can I do 3 above?  Changing the annotation to @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="firstName") doesn't work.

**Party's class**

```
@Entity
public  class Party implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},targetEntity=Organizer.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_Organizer",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Organizer id_Organizer;

    @Column(name="startDate")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private Timestamp start;
}
```

**Organizer's class**

```
@Entity
public  class Orgaznizer implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String firstName;

    @Basic
    private String lastName;

}
```

Comment: return where? what is making the call?

Comment: @Aeseir The call is a done from Javascript via ajax.  But it really doesn't matter because if I enter the URL into the browser I should still see the response printed in the browser's body.